# How to select certain children in my case

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have something like this

```
<ul id='nav'>
            <li><h1 id='unique' class='title'>Topic</h1></li>
            <li><h1 class='toptitle'>Department</h1></li>
            <li><a  class='title' href='#'>test1</a></li>
            <li><h1 class='toptitle'>test2</h1></li>
            <li><a  class='title' href='#'>test1</a></li>
</ul>
```

I want to change the background of my `li` when user clicks the button. However, I want to keep the '`#unique`' background.

I have something like

```
$('.title').on('click', function(e){
      $(this).closest('ul').find('li').not('#unique').css({'background-color':'white'})  //change all li background except the first li
      $(this).parent().css({'background-color':'#DDDDDD'})
})
```

I want to change all `li` background except the first `li`. My codes don't do it. Can anyone help me about it? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because the id is not on the li, it is on a child. You can use the [has selector](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) to find it.

```
.not('#unique')
```

to

```
.not(':has(#unique)')
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JQsm9/)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to exclude the first child, you can use the selector `:first-child`

```js
$(this).closest('ul').find('li').not(':first-child').css({'background-color':'white'})
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4eVWt/)